# Error while converting a mongoDB Cluster into a Replica Set

Tags: mongodb

We followed the [instructions](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/tutorial/convert-sharded-cluster-to-replica-set/) to Convert a Cluster with a Single Shard into a Replica Set but as soon as we restarted the first Secondary (of a total of 3 secondaries + 1 primary) without  the `--shardsvr` option, all database clients (which are connecting already directly to the replSet without problems instead to the mongoS routers) received the following error while querying the database:

`Query failed with error code 211 and error message 'Cache Reader No keys found for HMAC that is valid for time: { ts: Timestamp(1585205456, 422) } with id: 6802955028354040016' on server our-db-server.domain.com:27017`

Therefore, we have immediately reversed the change. 
This error makes it impossible for us to convert the single-shard cluster into a standalone replSet. 
How to proceed?
Thanks!

Comment: The replica set won't function properly if yoy remove the `--shardsvr` option from only some members.  I think you will need to stop all of the members, remove the shardsvr option, and then restart them all.

Comment: Thanks Joe for the insights. So this would mean that the conversion could not take place without downtime. This should have been mentioned in the mongodb documentation!

Comment: Which storage engine? MMAPv1 or WiredTiger?

Comment: @Breedly WiredTiger

Answer (score 2):

I think the likely case is that the [vector clock](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/66f0361/src/mongo/db/s/README.md#the-vector-clock-and-causal-consistency) [clusterTime](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/66f0361/src/mongo/db/s/README.md#clustertime) is out of sync between replicas and or your client.

This [section specifically](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/66f0361/src/mongo/db/s/README.md#key-management) deals with how clusterTime is used for [HMAC signatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC).

[clusterTime](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/66f0361/src/mongo/db/s/README.md#clustertime) ticks on essentially every write to a PRIMARY so if you are changing the cluster's configuration in some way a tick would be captured. If your client does not correctly update its [clusterTime](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/66f0361/src/mongo/db/s/README.md#clustertime) after that tick it may get caught trying to use an old key for [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) signing of its requests.

Likely something is wrong with the cluster as stated above and the client [heartbeat](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/blob/v1.3.5/x/mongo/driver/topology/server.go#L442) isn't correcting the clock.

It could also be that your client library is not updating clusterTime when doing auth hand shakes as per this ticket: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/GODRIVER-1584.

---

I'm just going to take some notes here as I am *also* seeing this error when upgrading from 3.6 to 4.0.21.

I figured out this is returned from MongoDB by searching the repo using [sourcegraph](https://sourcegraph.com/search?q=repo:%5Egithub%5C.com/mongodb/mongo%24+No+keys+found+for&patternType=literal).

The error comes from [KeysCollectionManager::getKeysForValidation](https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/mongodb/mongo/-/blob/src/mongo/db/keys_collection_manager.cpp#L106), and is rooted in the [KeysCollectionCache::getInternalByKeyId](https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/mongodb/mongo/-/blob/src/mongo/db/keys_collection_cache.cpp#L149-152) method.

This particular [KeysCollectionManager](https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/mongodb/mongo@66f0361649bc5239460a6764cacf6c448fe190e9/-/blob/src/mongo/db/mongod_main.cpp#L663) does seem to only instantiate itself for replicasets. It is instantiated using [kKeyManagerPurposeString](https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/mongodb/mongo@66f0361649bc5239460a6764cacf6c448fe190e9/-/blob/src/mongo/db/keys_collection_manager.cpp#L52), whose value is always "HMAC". It's purpose, I'm not sure.

The [globalsign/mgo](https://sourcegraph.com/search?q=No+keys+found+for+HMAC+that+is+valid+for+time&patternType=literal) fork of the go client has some test harnesses that indicate that they've run into this before, but don't necessarily know where it comes from. They hypothesize it only happens when your replica set uses an internal auth keyfile.

I would hope that this situation would be resolved by multiple retries until successful. I wager it's mostly an issue of the cluster not being in a ready state.

My situation is vastly different from the question's as I am using a stand alone replica set without sharding. I would hope retrying requests would help, but it could be a cluster membership issue that needs to be resolved on MongoDB itself.

This [post in the MongoDB community](https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/adding-wiredtiger-node-to-mmapv1-replica-set-leads-to-no-keys-found-for-hmac/5167) likely indicates it is a cluster internals issue and looking for suspicious MongoDB logs would be key.

Comment: This issue is promising: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-40762?attachmentViewMode=list

Comment: I did not mention in my original question that our clients were using only the java driver. All our servers have the same time since their times are synchronized by ntp servers. Do you think that your answer may still be related to our issue?

Comment: Ours wound up being reproducible when we ran our tests on MMAP. So, it seems are getting the issue for different reasons. What version of the Java driver? And do you continue to experience this?

Comment: We are using version 3.10 or newer. We are using wired tiger as storage engine for several years already (no MMAP anymore). We did not encounter this issue again but I think we did not convert a cluster to a replSet since then.

Answer (score 0):

We also had this error, after restarting all members its fixed!